# UIView with touchesMoved event for scrolling UIimages from web?

Tags: iphone

Actually i need a uiview on which touch moved event will be attached and i need that when we swipe left and right the images should be downloaded from web and should be displayed on uiview ,only one full image will be displayed on this uiview.

Second thing which i need is that when user viewing any image then their next and previous images should be downloaded, for fast viewing on images.

Let me know if i am not able to convey my question's message to u.

Thanks in advance to all my great developers friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below link will help you

> https://github.com/vvanhee/MWPhotoBrowser